# Создание событий при помощи trackChanges

Tags: javascript, события

Пытаюсь создать событие при изменении переменной при помощи пакета TrackChanges.
Но вылетает ошибка "This name is already being used" при попытке создать observer даже для самой простой переменной:

```
const TrackChanges = require('track-changes-js');

const trackChanges = new TrackChanges();
const CreateTemplate = (nTitle, imageSrc, ElementType, Selector) => {
  let a = 1;
  trackChanges.addObserver('obs', () => a);}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: На какое имя он ругается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вынесла объявление observer из функции, а хэндлер можно объявлять в ней. Это решило проблему

Answer (score 1):

Если смотреть [документацию](https://www.npmjs.com/package/track-changes-js), которая указывает что вам нужно указать имя обзерверу

```
trackChanges.addObserver('obs_' + nTitle, () => a); // используйте что-то уникальное
trackChanges.addHandler('obs_' + nTitle, nTitleHandler);
```

Вы добавляете постоянно `addObserver` с именем `obs`  для переменной `a`. Я думаю что вам нужно определять новый обзервер для каждого нового случая. А у вас постоянно один `obs`

Comment: заголовки могут быть любыми, как тогда отлавливать событие с рандомным именем?

Comment: НЕ РАНДОМНОЕ, а уникальное. Если создаете то нумеруйте хотябы или сделайте мапу по именам

Answer (score 0):

**Спасибо за использование моей библиотеки)**

Внесу ясности.

Наблюдатель должен иметь уникальное имя.
Библиотека во имя производительности использует одно хранилище где лежат эти имена наблюдателей.

Ваша проблема в том что у вас уже есть наблюдатель с именем 'obs' в другом месте, или файле.

**Обьявление наблюдателя:**
`trackChanges.addObserver('observer', () => value);`

Первый аргумент, имя наблюдателя. (observer)

Второй аргумент, наблюдаемая сущность которую возвращет функция (value)

---

**После этого вы можете добавить обработчик, их можно создавать неограниченое количевство.**

Первый аргумент, имя созданого наблюдателя (observer)

Второй аргумент, колбэк который вызывается при изменении сущности, аргументом будет измененная сущность.

`trackChanges.addHandler('observer', (changes) => console.log(changes));`
`trackChanges.addHandler('observer', (changes) => console.table({changes}));`